# Using ChronoForms V5 is it possible to only allow 1 submission per email address?

Tags: mysql, joomla, joomla3.0, chronoforms

I'm using ChronoForms V5 on Joomla 3.

I'd set up a form for people to enter a competition, the form sends the data entered into a new table in the MySQL database. This all works.

My question is, how can I make it so only 1 entry can be submitted per email address? I'd like to prevent multiple entries from the same email address.

Many thanks
SalcombeWeb

Comment: I've partly answered my question by using the Custom ServerSide Validation suggested on the Chrono Engine forum [link] (http://www.chronoengine.com/forums/posts/f2/t23171.html), however instead of displaying the error message it returns an Allowed Memory Size fatal error on chronoform.php. Any ideas?

Comment: Post the code you are using in the custom serverside validation event.